# How to calculate rotation matrix and translation vector of camera using four points

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera-calibration, perspectivecamera, pose-estimation

The perspective transformation from 3D object to 2D image plane is:

```
s[u v 1]^t = A[R T][X Y Z 1]^t
```

where the A is camera params that are known.

In Matlab, we can use an "extrinsic" function to calculate R and T given four corresponding image points and world points: `[u v]` and `[X Y]`.

However, there are 13 variables (including `s`), and we only have 12 equations here. (BTW, I set `Z = 0`, is this right? or `Z` can be any value?). How can I compute `s`, `R` and `T`? What's the math process of it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called [Perspective-n-Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective-n-Point).

You can find some reference in the literature (e.g. [Model-Based Object Pose in 25 Lines of Code](https://my.nps.edu/documents/106608270/107784480/Scoring+-+DeMenthon+-+Model-Based+Object+Pose+in+25+Lines+of+Code.pdf) in 1995, newer methods exist). Here some courses on this topic:

- [Lecture 23: 3-D Pose Object Recognition](https://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~ramani/cmsc426/Lecture23_3Dpose.pdf)
- [3D Pose Estimation](http://home.in.tum.de/~grembowi/ar2004_05/3dPoseEstimation_presentation.pdf)